# Can I convert safetensors to TensorFlow Lite model?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to AI and Python.

I have an AI model with the anime.**safetensors** extension. I want to **import** this to **Firebase ML** but **is not a supported file type.** I am getting error. How can I **import** an **AI** file with **.safetensor** extension into **Firebase ML**?
I tried this code but It’s not working.

```
    import tensorflow as tf

# upload model
model = tf.saved_model.load("path/to/your/safetensors/model")

# Convert model to TensorFlow Lite format
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("path/to/your/safetensors/model")
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save TensorFlow Lite
with open("converted_model.tflite", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_mo
```